# Time-based installable trigger - example from documentation doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

In Sheets add-on, I try create time-based trigger that will run some time after last edit in spreadsheet.

```
try
{
  // create new trigger
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(triggerFunctionName)
    .timeBased()
    .after(timeout)
    .create();
}
catch(err)
{
  console.log(err);
}
```

To test it, I set timeout to 30 seconds in ms:

```
let timeout = 30 * 1000;
```

But it failed with this log in Cloud Logging:

> { [Exception: Clock events must be scheduled at least 1 hour(s) apart.] name: 'Exception' }

I checked with documentation for [`after`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#afterdurationmilliseconds) and changed timeout from 30 seconds to 10 minutes, like in documentation example [image]

```
let timeout = 10 * 60 * 1000;
```

but no luck - same exception is thrown:

> { [Exception: Clock events must be scheduled at least 1 hour(s) apart.] name: 'Exception' }

Is there anything that I missed? Why time-based trigger can't be created to run after 10 minutes?

Comment: Use ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers() and check if you have other triggers defined already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot depends on the context in which a time-driven trigger is created.

Since this trigger was created from an add-on it **cannot** be fired in intervals less than one hour. Here's a quote from the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers), note the text highlighted in bold:

> *A time-driven trigger (also called a clock trigger) is similar to a cron job in Unix. Time-driven triggers let scripts execute at a particular time or on a recurring interval, as frequently as every minute or as infrequently as once per month. **(Note that an add-on can use a time-driven trigger once per hour at most.)** The time may be slightly randomized — for example, if you create a recurring 9 a.m. trigger, Apps Script chooses a time between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m., then keeps that timing consistent from day to day so that 24 hours elapse before the trigger fires again.*